# Unity error "The name 'ZipFile' does not exist in the current context"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, dll

I have already searched this issue but none of the answers could solve my problem.

I just installed Unity and Visual Studio in my laptop and in my Desktop PC. In the laptop everything works out of the box, I can open my project and work on it but in the PC when I open the project I get these errors:

```
Library\PackageCache\com.unity.connect.share@1.0.9-preview\Editor\store\Middleware.cs(75,13): error CS0103: The name 'ZipFile' does not exist in the current context
Library\PackageCache\com.unity.xiaomi@1.0.3\XiaomiSupport\AppStoreSettings.cs(7,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Store' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEngine' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
Library\PackageCache\com.unity.xiaomi@1.0.3\XiaomiSupport\AppStoreSettings.cs(28,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AppInfo' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I can solve the last 2 removing the Xiaomi SDK from the Package Manager but I don't know what to do about the ZipFile error.

This is the code of **Middleware.cs**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using Unity.Connect.Share.UIWidgets.Redux;
using Unity.UIWidgets.async;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

namespace Unity.Connect.Share.Editor.store
{
    public class ShareMiddleware
    {
        private static UnityWebRequest uploadRequest;
        private const string webglSharingFile = "webgl_sharing";
        private const string zipName = "connectwebgl.zip";
        private const string thumbnail = "thumbnail.png";
        private const string uploadEndpoint = "/api/webgl/upload";
        private const string queryProgressEndpoint = "/api/webgl/progress";
        private const int ZipFileLimitBytes = 100 * 1024 * 1024;

        public static Middleware<AppState> Create() {
            return (store) => (next) => (action) => {
                var result = next(action);

                switch (action)
                {
                    case ShareStartAction shared:
                        ZipAndShare(shared.title, store);
                        break;    
                    case UploadStartAction upload:
                        Upload(store);
                        break;
                    case QueryProgressAction query:
                        CheckProgress(store, query.key);
                        break;
                    case StopUploadAction stopUpload:
                        StopUploadAction();
                        break;
                    case NotLoginAction login:
                        CheckLoginStatus(store);
                        break;
                }
                return result;
            };
        }

        private static void ZipAndShare(string title, Store<AppState> store)
        {
            store.Dispatch(new TitleChangeAction { title = title});

            var buildOutputDir = store.state.shareState.buildOutputDir;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(buildOutputDir) || !Directory.Exists(buildOutputDir)) {
                store.Dispatch(new OnErrorAction { errorMsg = "Please build project first!" });
                return;
            }

            if (Zip(store)) {
                store.Dispatch(new UploadStartAction());
            }
        }

        private static bool Zip(Store<AppState> store)
        {
            var projectDir = Directory.GetParent(Application.dataPath).FullName;
            var buildOutputDir = store.state.shareState.buildOutputDir;
            var destPath = Path.Combine(projectDir, zipName);

            File.Delete(destPath);

            CopyThumbnail(store);

            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(buildOutputDir, destPath);
            var fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(destPath);

            if (fileInfo.Length > ZipFileLimitBytes) {
                store.Dispatch(new OnErrorAction{errorMsg = $"Max. allowed WebGL game .zip size is {Utils.FormatBytes(ZipFileLimitBytes)}."});
                return false;
            } else {
                store.Dispatch(new ZipPathChangeAction{ zipPath = destPath });
                return true;
            } 
        }

        private static void CopyThumbnail(Store<AppState> store)
        {
            var buildOutputDir = store.state.shareState.buildOutputDir;
            var thumbnailDestPath = Path.Combine(buildOutputDir, thumbnail);

            File.Delete(thumbnailDestPath);

            var thumbnailDir = store.state.shareState.thumbnailDir;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(thumbnailDir)) {
                return;
            }


            FileUtil.CopyFileOrDirectory(thumbnailDir, thumbnailDestPath);
        }

        private static void Upload(Store<AppState> store)
        {
            var token = UnityConnectSession.instance.GetAccessToken();
            if (token.Length == 0)
            {
                CheckLoginStatus(store);
                return;
            }

            var path = store.state.shareState.zipPath;
            var title = store.state.shareState.title;
            var buildGUID = store.state.shareState.buildGUID;

            var baseUrl = getAPIBaseUrl();
            var projectId = GetProjectId();
            var formSections = new List<IMultipartFormSection>();

            formSections.Add(new MultipartFormDataSection("title", title));

            if (buildGUID.Length > 0) {
                formSections.Add(new MultipartFormDataSection("buildGUID", buildGUID));
            }

            if (projectId.Length > 0)
            {
                formSections.Add(new MultipartFormDataSection("projectId", projectId));
            }



            formSections.Add(new MultipartFormFileSection("file", 
                File.ReadAllBytes(path), Path.GetFileName(path), "application/zip"));

            uploadRequest = UnityWebRequest.Post(baseUrl + uploadEndpoint, formSections);
            uploadRequest.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");
            uploadRequest.SetRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHTTPREQUEST");

            var op = uploadRequest.SendWebRequest();
            ConnectShareEditorWindow.StartCoroutine(updateProgress(store, uploadRequest));

            op.completed += operation =>
            {
                if(uploadRequest.isNetworkError || uploadRequest.isHttpError) {
                    Debug.Log(uploadRequest.error);
                    if (uploadRequest.error != "Request aborted")
                    {
                        store.Dispatch(new OnErrorAction {errorMsg = "Internal server error"});
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    var response = JsonUtility.FromJson<UploadResponse>(op.webRequest.downloadHandler.text);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.key))
                    {
                        store.Dispatch(new QueryProgressAction {key = response.key});
                    }
                }
            };
        }

        private static void StopUploadAction()
        {
            if (uploadRequest != null)
            {
                uploadRequest.Abort();
            }
        }

        private static void CheckProgress(Store<AppState> store, string key)
        {
            var token = UnityConnectSession.instance.GetAccessToken();
            if (token.Length == 0)
            {
                CheckLoginStatus(store);
                return;
            }

            key = key??store.state.shareState.key;
            var baseUrl = getAPIBaseUrl();
            var uploadRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get($"{baseUrl + queryProgressEndpoint}?key={key}");
            uploadRequest.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");
            uploadRequest.SetRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHTTPREQUEST");
            var op = uploadRequest.SendWebRequest();

            op.completed += operation =>
            {
                if(uploadRequest.isNetworkError || uploadRequest.isHttpError) {
                    Debug.Log(uploadRequest.error);
                }
                else
                {
                    var response = JsonUtility.FromJson<GetProgressResponse>(op.webRequest.downloadHandler.text);

                    store.Dispatch(new QueryProgressResponseAction {response = response});
                    if (response.progress == 100 || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.error))
                    {
                        SaveProjectID(response.projectId);
                        return;
                    }

                }

                ConnectShareEditorWindow.StartCoroutine(wait(1.5f)).promise.Then((obj) =>
                {
                    store.Dispatch(new QueryProgressAction());
                });
            };
        }

        private static void SaveProjectID(string projectId)
        {
            if (projectId.Length == 0)
            {
                return;
            }     

            var writer = new StreamWriter(webglSharingFile, false);
            writer.Write(projectId);
            writer.Close();
        }

        private static string GetProjectId()
        {
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(webglSharingFile))
            {
                return "";
            }

            var reader = new StreamReader(webglSharingFile);
            var projectId = reader.ReadLine();

            reader.Close();
            return projectId;
        }

        private static IEnumerator updateProgress(Store<AppState> store, UnityWebRequest request)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (request.isDone)
                {
                    break;
                }

                int progress = (int) (Mathf.Clamp(request.uploadProgress, 0, 1) * 100);
                store.Dispatch(new UploadProgressAction {progress = progress});
                yield return new UIWidgetsWaitForSeconds(0.5f);
            }

            yield  return null;
        }

        private static void CheckLoginStatus(Store<AppState> store)
        {
            var token = UnityConnectSession.instance.GetAccessToken();
            if (token.Length == 0)
            {
                ConnectShareEditorWindow.StartCoroutine(wait(2f)).promise.Then((obj) =>
                {
                    store.Dispatch(new NotLoginAction());
                });
            }
            else
            {
                store.Dispatch(new LoginAction());
            }

        }

        private static IEnumerator wait(float seconds)
        {
            yield return new UIWidgetsWaitForSeconds(seconds);
        }

        private static string getAPIBaseUrl()
        {
            var env = UnityConnectSession.instance.GetEnvironment();
            if (env == "staging")
            {
                return "https://connect-staging.unity.com";
            }
            else if (env == "dev")
            {
                return "https://connect-dev.unity.com";
            }

            return "https://connect.unity.com";
        }

    }

    [Serializable]
    public class UploadResponse
    {
        public string key;
    }


    [Serializable]
    public class GetProgressResponse
    {
        public string projectId;
        public string url;
        public int progress;
        public string error;
    }

}
```

I notice that the project in my laptop has 3 .dll files that the project in the PC doesn't have. If I copy these files while the project is open the errors diseappear, but when I open the project again the files get deleted. I somehow need to find a way so that Unity doesn't delete these files.

Can you please help me? I'm getting desperate. Keep in mind that I just started developing with Unity so I'm not familiar with the terminology.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have same version of Net on both machines and same version of Windows on both machines.  You may need to publish and install using serup.exe for application to run.  Net uses windows dll and if they are not the same version on two machine code will not run.  Publish updates windows dll so code will run.

Comment: @jdweng I have Net 4.8.03752 on both machines

Comment: What is your unity version?

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 2019.3.12f1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a Unity bug.

In **UnityEditor** go to: **[Window]->[Package manager]->[Share WebGL Game]->: Select your version and click to "Remove" Button or update to the latest version.**

Comment: Ok, it worked but what if I want to use that package? Thanks btw

Comment: Update to latest version, from 1.0.9 to 1.2.0.